# having trouble of displaying the data fetched from the endpoint of the flask app

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, flask

Using the create-react-app, I have created a simple React app to display the data fetched from the Flask endpoint. Though the fetch function can fetch the data from the HTTP endpoint, the map function can not read the retrieved data. The app  produces errors like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataTime' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/정보기획팀/Dropbox/yu_project/yu_blog_project/air_quality_react/src/DataList.js:10
   7 | return(
   8 |  <div>
   9 |      {data.map((datum, i) => {
> 10 |          return <Data key={i} time={datum[i].dataTime} pm10={datum[i].pm10Value} pm25={datum[i].pm25Value} />;
     | ^  11 |      })}
  12 |  </div>
  13 | )
```

The App.js is

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DataList from './DataList';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            airData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://210.123.33.247/airData')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    airData: data
                })
            );
    }

    render() {
        const {airData} = this.state;
        console.log('air data from the state ', airData);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p>Data from the air quality</p>
                <DataList data={this.state.airData} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And the DataList.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import Data from './Data';

const DataList = ({data}) => {
    console.log('from DataList', data[0]);
    console.log('pm value', data[3]);
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((datum, i) => {
                return (
                    <Data
                        key={i}
                        time={datum[i].dataTime}
                        pm10={datum[i].pm10Value}
                        pm25={datum[i].pm25Value}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DataList;
```

And the Data.js is

```
import React from 'react';

const Data = ({time, pm10, pm25}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{pm10}</p>
      <p>{pm25}</p>
      <p>{time}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Data
```

The index.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I appreciate it if someone please help me to locate the error. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function is a for loop which its first param is the object not the index, meaning

```
{data.map((datum, i) => {
            return (
                <Data
                    key={i}
                    time={datum[i].dataTime}
                    pm10={datum[i].pm10Value}
                    pm25={datum[i].pm25Value}
                />
            );
        })}
```

should change to:

```
{data.map((datum, i) => {
                return (
                    <Data
                        key={i}
                        time={datum.dataTime}
                        pm10={datum.pm10Value}
                        pm25={datum.pm25Value}
                    />
                );
            })}
```

Comment: To check the data structure, I did console.log('pm value', data[3]); as shown in the DataList.js.  It returned {pm10Value: "31", o3Value: "0.011", pm25Value: "25", coValue: "0.5", dataTime: "2017-12-13 13:00", …}. It does not make sense the map function can't retrieve the data element from it.

Comment: Yes, I did that with no avail.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct. It worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a `for` loop, which will not be executable within a `return` statement. So remove the primary return statement and change the `const` to the given below code snippet

```
const DataList = ({data}) => {
  {data.map((datum, i) => {
     return (
       <Data
          key={i}
          time={datum[i].dataTime}
          pm10={datum[i].pm10Value}
          pm25={datum[i].pm25Value}
        />
      );
    })}
  );
};
```

For error stating `dataTime for undefined`, check whether the inbound/incoming data from `flask` have hash within hash, if so you have to use `Object.values(data.map((dataum, i) => {function})`

Comment: It did not work. It returned the error: DataList(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.